# TinyMCE iframe encodes contents

Tags: iframe, tinymce, facebook-instant-articles

Inserting an iframe into TinyMCE with HTML contents rather than a `src` attribute encodes everything and breaks the contents.

Eg: inserting this via the View Source or Embed plugin:

`<iframe><p>hello</p></iframe>`

Will result in this when you view the Source again:

`<iframe width="300" height="150" data-mce-fragment="1">&amp;lt;P&amp;gt;hello&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;</iframe>`

Is there any way to stop this or a setting in the `init` which causes this?

If anyone wonders why I would need this over using a `src`, it's because I'm trying to format articles for Facebooks's new Instant Article thing which requires embedded posts/tweets etc to be wrapped in a `<figure><iframe>[code]</iframe></figure>` format.

Comment: When I load your HTML into TinyMCE I don't get the escaped data you suggest.  Can you create a TinyMCE Fiddle with your configuration that leads to this happening?

Comment: @MichaelFromin I discovered what was causing this issue earlier, I've added it as the accepted answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why this happened as I was trying to narrow down the problem by testing it out on [fiddle.tinymce.com](http://fiddle.tinymce.com). This encoding issue didn't happen on the fiddle, so I stripped back my own `init` thinking it was maybe the codemirror plugin, but it turned out to be the **[fontawesome 2.0.6](https://github.com/josh18/TinyMCE-FontAwesome-Plugin)** plugin *(it's now on 2.0.8 but I couldn't get that version to work so am unsure if it has changed the way it works since 2.0.6).*

The plugin does a `var content = parser.parseFromString(e.content, 'text/html');` on `BeforeSetContent` and `GetContent` to do some nonEditable class changes. This caused certain HTML elements to become encoded in the source code.

Long story short, I removed the parser and modified the plugin and my problem is solved!